# My provision profile is about to expire in one day (iOS)?

Tags: ios6

My original Provision profile expires tomorrow. I have renewed my annual application developer ($99). This was an ad-hoc provision profile. I still want to renew this provision profile. I can't seem to find the right answer to this? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has provided each and every documentation for profile management. Just log in to your [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com) profile and then go with this link [Replacing an Expired Certificate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW3)

Here is one more documentation:

**Distribution Certificates Must Be Renewed Periodically**

```
A distribution certificate is valid for one year from date of issue. After it expires, you won’t be able sign and install apps on your devices although this will not affect any existing apps in the App Store.

To continue distribution, navigate to the Devices organizer in Xcode. Select the expired profile and click Renew Profile in the red bar at the top. This will renew your expired certificate and add it to the provisioning profile. After you get a new distribution certificate, you can submit new apps or app updates to the App Store.

If you are enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, revoking your distribution certificate will make your app fail on any installed devices. Only revoke your certificate if your app or private key have been compromised. You can create a second distribution certificate six months before your existing certificate expires. The overlapping certificate allows you to continue to build and distribute your app once your first certificate expires.
```

Find this one over [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html)

Duplicate Question: [Proper way to renew distribution certificate for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios)

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Renewal from Xcode didn't work for me. I am going to try to revoke my certificate and add a new one. I would like to renew my ad-hoc distribution for another year? Can I ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess you would require to create new certificate for that one. To renew profile, go to the https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action  --> iOS Provisioning Portal  --> Provisioning --> Renew 

Refer this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

The link to "Replacing and expired certificate" is broken. The"Find this one here" link is "retired" on apple's site.