# Advice on how to renew ios certificate

Tags: xcode, certificate, renewal

My exsisting distrubution certificate for iOS development will soon expire, what is the correct steps to renew it (I use Xcode 6.1.1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to renew distribution certificate for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios)

Comment: The link above seem to show a older version of Xcode, I don't get that account - settings view...

Comment: check this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: That seem to apply when your in a team which I'm not .....