# Best way to renew the certificates for signing Apple products

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

My development and distribution certificates are expiring today. I have followed below link and got infos about creating a new one.

[Proper way to renew distribution certificate for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios)

My questions are listed below:

1. What is the best way, revoke certificate and create a new one before certificate expires or wait for it to expire and then create a new one?
2. What will happen to the old one in keychain access, do i have to manually delete them?
3. We uses the same certificate in two different machine, do we have to delete the old one from machine's keychain on the machine and then create the new one and then export the new keys to other machine?
4. one of my provisioning profile has expiry date of 26/07/2017 however if I am changing the development certificate and distribution certificate so I need to edit and regenerate the provisioning profile as well because I am changing the certificate. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

1) I would advise that you wait until they expire, then request new certificates in the certificates & identifiers section of the developer portal. Your certificates expiring will not affect any current apps you may have on the app store, it will only remove your ability to sign code. Once they expire, follow the steps to create new development and distribution certificates.

2) There is no need to  manually delete your certificates from keychain access. Just make sure to choose the current ones in your Project's build settings.

3) Since you have two machines, you will have to download these 2 certificates to your other machine as well and add to keychain access.

4) Yes, you will need to regenerate your provisioning profiles using your new certificates, download them, then install them to xcode. You may also want to delete your old provisioning profiles. To do this, go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->(Choose apple ID here)->View Details. Now, right click on expiring profiles, hit show in finder, then delete them from finder. Also, remember to update which profiles your project uses in your build settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think selecting the valid one in build settings is a good thing however it will be messy. If I will delete the old ones, does that have any effect?

only downloading the certificate will do nothing in second machine as they require the public/private key is this correct?

Comment: @Ian....could you please let me know about the expired key in keychain....do I have to delete them?

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping. Only expiring provisioning profiles will cause issues in code. For sake of being organized, they can be deleted manually but it will not affect your project.