# Do I need to update the provisional profile of the app if my provisional profile expires when the app is in production?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

My provisional profile is going to expire by this month.What should I do now? 
*Do I need to create a new distribution provisional profile or update a old profile?*
**How do I change the distribution provisional profile without changing the version when the app is in production ?**

**If my provisional profile & certificate have expired, then my app will work or not?**

Comment: Possible duplicate item. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10760224/2035845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to renew distribution certificate for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your development or distribution certificate **expires**, remove it and request a new certificate in Xcode.
Re-creating your development or distribution certificates doesn’t affect apps that you’ve **submitted** to the store nor does it affect your ability to update them.

Comment: Welcome - @Gugan

Comment: You should probably go ahead and recreate things, as you will need them if you want to submit a new version.  If Apple releases an iOS update, you want to make sure you have the ability to submit to the store if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

1) Deleted the Provisioning Profile from the Xcode Organizer.

2) Deleted the same thing from the developer provisioning portal.

3) Again from Xcode organizer check marked the auto provision and clicked 'Refresh'. it asked for the credentials and in a few seconds added the renewed Team Provisioning Profile.

4) It also added the new profile in the developer provisioning portal.

Comment: Already my app is in live and its provisional profile & certificates are going to get expire? If my provisional profile & certificate have expired, then my app  will work or not.

Comment: Thank you! userar