# Apple says "Your iOS Distribution Certificate expiring" what i need to do

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ios-provisioning

I got this mail from Apple.

> Your iOS Distribution Certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To generate a new certificate, sign in and visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

I get some information from [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios) but I want to know what I need to do if I modify my existing app. Will I able to update in future the same app with new certificate and new profile. Is that I need to revoke and generate the new certificate. Thanks for your help and comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per new updates, you don't need to renew the certificate as a separate action.  The renewal is based on the expiration of the Apple developer account.  By taking the action of renewing your membership, this will automatically renew your certificates.

Comment: I renewed my membership (by paying the 100 USD annual cost) but these two certificates are still going to expire in a month. What should I do?

Comment: @sports they will auto renew when the time comes. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 11):

It is just a reminder of the certificate that is going to be expired very soon in future.

> I want to know what I need to do if I modify my existing app. Will I able to update in future the same app with new certificate and new profile.

**Yes**, You can always able to create new certificates (Some has limitation to create) and use these certificate to generate new mobile provisioning profile or regenerate mobile provisioning profile using the new certificates.

Using old certificate (Expired) you can not able to run build on device and not able to publish app on App Store.

The new certificate will not affect on your app. In simple words, certificates are being used to run app on device, publish app on App Store, push notification, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Mahendra so what i need to do. Wait for expiring or create a new provisioning profile and certificate. Does the provisioning profile also expire?

Comment: You can invoke those certificate and create a new one right now OR you can wait for expiration and then revoke certificate and then create a new one.

Comment: I would suggest to create new one right now. and regenerate all provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks so much i was getting confuse for this from 20 days what i need to do. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks @A.Goutam. Cheers!!

Comment: @A.Goutam As per new updates, i think you don't need to create new certificate check if the developer account is not expiring, as i can see from my past experience, the certificate will be renewed according to the developer account validity.

Comment: Apple informed him via email about the expiration of the certificates.

Comment: @HarjotSingh thanks for your message where i can get this details. Can you provide me any link or document for this. This is really very urgent for me

Comment: Details is in your developer account, open your developer account and check the validity now.You don't need to create new certificates, even if you do as @Mahendra GP told you, you can do that too.

Comment: @Mahendra GP i understand sometimes, it is due to the expiration of the account, anyways, its upto him now what he want to do.

Comment: @HarjotSingh i have loged in my developer account but i can not find the validity now. Where is the option

Comment: @A.Goutam In your developer account, open membership tab and check the expiration of the developer account.

Comment: @HarjotSingh  i get this this is telling February 22, 2019 but auto renew Membership is on.

Comment: and When your certificate is expiring?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188789/discussion-between-harjot-singh-and-a-goutam).

Comment: If I ignore this, will my app who has been live for several years get taken down from AppStore? Or will this only stop me from uploading an update?

Comment: @Esqarrouth Your app will remain in the App Store.  When you make modifications to the app in Xcode and your annual fee has been paid, the certificate will be updated with a new expiration.