# Expired iOS Developer/Distribution Certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

So, my first App is on the AppStore for almost a year now. I started receiving notices from Apple that my iOS Distribution Certificate will expire in 30 days time. That's fine — they expire.

But, the email says to go to Certificates, Provisioning and Identities to renew — only there is nothing there that specifically guides me through such a process that I can see — and it's a very clean, spartan portal so I imagine I would see something especially if I was directed to go there specifically for this reason.

As I've never renewed a certificate, I wonder if anyone might be able to guide me through the process? There seems to be no clear answer.
My concern is that the expired certificate would somehow break the App currently in the store? (I don't know that it will, or will not — but I'm not excited to find out in real time.)

Am I meant to create a new certificate in Xcode? Does it need to be somehow applied to the current version of the App, or the one in the App Store, meaning I may need to publish a new version of the App for hygiene?
Any pointers or help are greatly appreciated.

Julian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to renew distribution certificate for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

If your Apple Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to upload new apps or updates signed with the expired or revoked certificate to the App Store.

https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/

For updating the app you need to generate new certificate.