# iOS distribution certificate expires - Is a new certificate created automatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have just uploaded a new version of my app to App Store Connect using Xcode. During the upload process I was notified, that my Distribution Certificate will expire in about a week.

I found dozens of questions about what will happen when a distribution certificate expires: Nothing will change on existing apps, but one cannot upload updates or new apps without a new certificate.

However, I found no information on how to get a new certificate. In my project I selected the option that Xcode automatically handles certificates and signing but does this include the Distribution Certificate or just the app specific certificates?

So, do I have to create a new Distribution Certificate manually or will this be done automatically by Xcode?

EDIT:

I also found many answers explaining how to create new certificates. However, all these answers are years old and refer to Xcode versions which did not offer automatic signing. So the question is, if it is still necessary manually (re-)create a distribution certificate in 2021 using Xcode 13 or if this something from the past :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to renew distribution certificate for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759973/proper-way-to-renew-distribution-certificate-for-ios)

Comment: Thanks @auspicious99 Most of the answers to the linked question refer to pretty old Xcode versions. However, there is one answer from 2020 which states that this should be handled automatically nowadays.

Comment: @FLichter did you find a clear answer to this question? Most of the answers online are very old and the documentation from Apple is vague at best. If XCode is automatically managing signing, is any of this needed? I have some old certs that I am not even sure if they are being used, but I do not know what the process is to make sure they are renewed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 13, automatic certificates and signing means that the certificate is created automatically and held in the cloud, so there is nothing to do. You could probably delete your distribution identity / certificate right now and everything would go on working.

Comment: I have automatic signing checked in XCode, but I still have some certs on the Apple Developer portal. However, it is isn't clear if you still need to generate new ones or if those in the portal are even being used. Any idea on how to check if they are or not?