# What happens with the app in App Store if its provisioning profile expires?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app in the App Store that's distribution provisioning profile has expired yesterday. I already submitted today the update with the new profile, but it would be good to know, that the existing version will work or stop working? I downloaded the app today and it works, but it would be really useful for me if somebody could give me an exact answer.

Comment: Nothing will happen to it. That app is not linked to the provisioning profile that is on your developer portal. If you delete the profile on your portal, AppStore won't take down your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expiring App Store Provisioning Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128479/expiring-app-store-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app in the app store doesn't depend on its provisioning profile to run on user devices as it's signed by Apple. Just that you won't be able to run it on your provisioned test devices.