# Apple provisioning profile expired while app update was in review

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted an update for my app in iTunesconnect a couple of weeks ago. The update was approved, while it was waiting for review the provisioning profile expired.

I was going to do one last test with TestFlight before releasing the update, but TestFlight gives the "developer's certificate is no longer valid" error when I try to install it.

So my questions:
If I release the update, will new users downloading the app get this same message?

Will people trying to update get this message?

Is there any way to resolve this without submitting a new build (which will take another 2 weeks to get approved)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update will install and work just fine if installed through the public App Store, but not if installed through TestFlight.  The version released through the public App Store will be signed by Apple in a way that overrides your expired provisioning profile.

More details here:
[Expiring App Store Provisioning Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128479/expiring-app-store-provisioning-profile)

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. I released the update and it worked fine.